# Regex validate email : check several special character

Tags: regex

I need a regex email validation with special characters.

Rules:

- **Only one** special character .-
- Allow only a-z-A-Z0-9 after @
- Deny the subdomain

**Example of desired result:**

```
user@domain.com TRUE
user@subdomain.domain.com FALSE
alias-useruser@domain.com TRUE
alias--user@domain.com FALSE
alias.user@domain.com TRUE
alias.user.user@domain.com FALSE
-user@domain.com FALSE
user-@domain.com FALSE
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This satisfies your test data:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{1,}[-.]?[a-zA-Z]{1,}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,}\.[a-zA-Z]
```

[image: regexp test results]

See https://regex101.com/r/5eeV7g/1/